# How do I increase the refresh rate to 240Hz with a GeForce GTX 660?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, framerate

My monitor:  ACER 25 KG251QD 1ms 240Hz AMD FreeSync

Graphic Card: GeForce GTX 660
Cable: Display port

I can't set the [monitor refresh rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FXoD.png) higher than 120hz:

I also would like to turn G-sync on but there is lack of this option.
Do you know how can I change the refresh rate to higher than 120hz and turn on G-sync?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't use G-Sync unless you have a G-Sync enabled display.**

FreeSync displays are incompatible with the G-Sync feature on NVIDIA cards.

As far as your refresh rate, are you certain that the GeForce GTX 660 is capable of 240Hz?  The graphics card is from 2012, after all.  As far as I'm aware, there wasn't a single 240Hz display on the market in 2012.

The [specifications from NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/graphics-cards/geforce-gtx-660/specifications/) suggest that it can't handle 240Hz.